# factory pattern in GO (wrapper)

Tags: go

As a learning exercise, I set out to write a simple wrapper to wrap `"go.uber.org/zap"`, and maybe add some metrics (statsD) to each time my logging function is called to make this worthwhile.

The `.Info` implementation works as expected.

What is interesting, `.Infow` does not work.  I can not seem to get this to work for `...interface{}` types, and am getting the error:

```
2019-08-09T23:46:27.250-0400    DPANIC  zap/sugar.go:179    Ignored key without a value.    {"ignored": [{},{}]}
```

Full Implementation:

```
package ilogger

import (
    "reflect"

    "go.uber.org/zap"
)

type Logger interface {
    NewLogger(env string) logger
}

type logger struct {
    zapInstance zap.SugaredLogger
}

func NewLogger(env string) *logger {
    z := NewZapLogger(env)
    return &logger{
        zapInstance: *z,
    }
}

func NewZapLogger(env string) *zap.SugaredLogger {
    var zapInstance *zap.Logger
    if env == "production" {
        zapInstance, _ = zap.NewProduction()
    } else {
        zapInstance, _ = zap.NewDevelopment()
    }
    defer zapInstance.Sync() // flushes buffer, if any
    return zapInstance.Sugar()
}

// Info uses fmt.Sprint to construct and log a message.
func (l *logger) Info(args ...interface{}) {
    l.zapInstance.Info(args)
}

// Infow logs a message with some additional context. The variadic key-value
// pairs are treated as they are in With.
func (l *logger) Infow(msg string, keysAndValues ...interface{}) {
    things := make([]reflect.Value, len(keysAndValues))
    for k, in := range keysAndValues {
        things[k] = reflect.ValueOf(in)
    }
    l.zapInstance.Infow(msg, things)
}
```

How do i pass `...interface{}` to zap properly?

Source Documentation:

[article1](http://chrisarges.net/2016/05/20/creating-a-function-wrapper-in-golang.html)
[article2](https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/golang/2018-06-20-golang-factory-patterns/)

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters

Comment: ... just to add to the above comment: you should do the same with `Info`'s `args` value. Also in your `Infow` implementation you're turning each argument into a `reflect.Value` seemingly for no reason, unless you have an actual reason, do *not* do that, it is not required by `zap`'s `Infow`, and it is wasteful.

Comment: Folks, maybe you can add an example of how I can wrap sugar.Infow method?  I've tried passing `keyAndValues` through without using `reflect`, but the error is `DPANIC zap/sugar.go:179 Ignored key without a value. {"ignored": ["env","HI"]}`

Answer (score 0):

The devil lies in details.  As mentioned in the [docs](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters), the following is correct:

```
func (l *logger) Infow(msg string, keysAndValues ...interface{}) {
    l.zapInstance.Infow(msg, keysAndValues...)
}
```